# an error occured, please run package manager from the right click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see whats wrong

Tags: apt, 20.04

an error occured, please run package manager from the right click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see whats wrong.The error message was : 1'error: broken count>0'. This usually means that you have installed packages have unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're having dependancy issues with your APT package. In a new terminal run

```
sudo apt install <package name>
```

and put the output in your question when finished. This will give me the information required to better understand what is wrong. Please also put the name of the package / application you're trying to install.

Tip: You can use Ctrl + Alt + T to open a new terminal where you can type in the command.

Comment: Well i was not trying to install any package. Its an error which is coming on top right.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade` and see if it all works as expected.

Comment: sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server-10.3 : Depends: mariadb-client-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.34+maria~focal) but 1:10.3.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
 mariadb-server-core-10.3 : Breaks: mariadb-client-10.3 (< 1:10.3.34+maria~focal) but 1:10.3.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).